# Access navigationItem from protocol extension

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to access the navigationItem from a protocol extension? For example if I want to put the following code in a protocol extension:

```
let customTitleView = UIView() // some custom view
navigationItem.titleView = customTitleView
```

However, this comes up with an error saying the navigationItem is an unresolved identifier, i.e. it can't detect it. I guess this is because it's not a subclass of UIViewController. Is there an alternative way to get the navigationItem from a protocol extension?

Comment: Have you try it? Can you show us what have you done?

Comment: @Breek Just updated the question

Comment: What is the extension extending? If that class has access to the navigationItem, then the extension will have access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this work?

```
protocol NavigationBarStyleable {
    var titleView: UIView { get }
    func style()
}

extension NavigationBarStyleable where Self: UIViewController {
    var titleView: UIView {
        return UIView()
    }

    func style() {
        navigationItem.titleView = titleView
    }
}
```